# What is the significance of mark match in IPTABLES?

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, iptables, docker

I am trying to set up a Rancher site and struggling to get networking right. My health check containers are failing with "No route to host". I compared the IPTABLE rules with a working Rancher site and came across these rules that are set up in the working Rancher site:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
CATTLE_NETWORK_POLICY  all  --  10.42.0.0/16         10.42.0.0/16
CATTLE_FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain CATTLE_FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            mark match 0x1068
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            mark match 0x4000
```

`$ iptables-save | grep mark`

```
-A CATTLE_RAW_PREROUTING ! -i docker0 -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1068/0xffffffff`
-A CATTLE_RAW_PREROUTING ! -i docker0 -p udp -m udp --dport 4500 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1068/0xffffffff
-A CATTLE_FORWARD -m mark --mark 0x1068 -j ACCEPT
-A CATTLE_FORWARD -m mark --mark 0x4000 -j ACCEPT
```

My questions:

1. What are these rules? WHat is `mark match 0x168` and `mark match 0x4000` ?
2. How do I add these rules to my iptables? I only know how to add or remove standard tcp/udp ports from iptables and unable to find anything regading this? How do I add these rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP packets while within a Linux host have an attribute called **packet mark**. That is just a number.

These rules accept packets which have been given a packet mark value 0x1068 or 0x4000 (in the `PREROUTING` chain of the `mangle`, `raw` or `nat` chains).

### adding these rules

I assume you found the `CATTLE_FORWARD` rules in the `filter` table and the `CATTLE_RAW_PREROUTING` rules in the `raw` table.

```
# create the chain CATTLE_FORWARD
iptables -N CATTLE_FORWARD
iptables -t raw -N CATTLE_RAW_PREROUTING

# add the rules
iptables -A CATTLE_FORWARD -m mark --mark 0x1068 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A CATTLE_FORWARD -m mark --mark 0x4000 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t raw -A CATTLE_RAW_PREROUTING ! -i docker0 -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1068/0xffffffff
iptables -t raw -A CATTLE_RAW_PREROUTING ! -i docker0 -p udp -m udp --dport 4500 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1068/0xffffffff
```

But this is not enough. You also need rules in a different table which set this value. Otherwise the above rules will not do anything.

Comment: So, how do I add this rule? For example, if I need to expose port 80, I run something like `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW.....`. Similarly, how do I add this rule?

Comment: @Koshur I have extended my answer.

Comment: Got it, will try this. You mentioned that this will not be enough. What do you mean when you say that? If a process running on another server sends packets marked `0x1068` and `0x4000` to this server that has these rules, will the packets not be accepted?

Comment: @Koshur You cannot send packets with a packet mark to another host because this mark is a field in the Linux kernel data structure for each packet. There is no such field in an IP packet. As soon as the packet has left the host this information is lost. So all packets which arrive at a host have the packet mark value 0 until the receiving host sets some other value. Run `iptables-save` on the other system and search for `mark` rules.

Comment: On the other system, i found more references. I have updated these references in the question. I guess this is the reference you were talking about? How do I add these references?

Comment: @Koshur Why don't you just run `iptables-save` as I told you to?

Comment: I just did and found some entries. Added them to the question.

Comment: @Koshur I have modified my answer.